# VB.NET Create downloadable resource

Tags: vb.net

I've become stuck at this hurdle. I'm trying to create a database that clients fill in, however the client can set different database paths to view different information in the program. I want to create template databases so should they wish to create a new database it will work with the SQL queries the program uses.

I'm trying to save the templates in to the program so that when a button is clicked, the template file is "downloaded" (copied) to the clients desktop.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Resources page of the project properties and add any existing file, including a SQL Server MDF data file.  At run time, you can get the data of the file from the appropriate property of `My.Resources`.  The type of the data depends on the type of the file.  I'd expect that an MDF file would come back as a `Byte` array, which you can then write to a file or whatever.

That said, you don't want to make your EXE too big by embedding several sizeable data files in it.  You might be better off just using loose files in a subfolder or, if you're determined to use resources, create a satellite assembly, i.e. a DLL that contains just resources.

Comment: Thanks, the file type is `.accdb` if that makes any difference? I've read PDF files from a resource as a `FileStream`. Is this a similar approach? How would I get it to make a copy as opposed to just reading it in?

Comment: If you add  file named "MyDatabase.accdb" the way I specified earlier then you can get a `Byte` array in code from `My.Resources.MyDatabase` and write it to a file using `File.WiteAllBytes`.